# Redux devtools on a hermes react-native app

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

I want to use redux devtools on our **react-native** app that's using `react-native 0.67.1` and **hermes**.

I don't mind using any known tools (like **react-native-debugger**, or **flipper**), but I was blocked on pretty much all of my attempts by various issues so far.

The community is currently on a weird state where:

- `react-native-debugger` doesn't work with hermes
- `flipper` gives us `Plugin ... is unavailable` errors, and it feels like those plugins have been abandoned
- `redux-devtools` has moved their packages (@redux-devtools) without really providing great docs for react-native projects (does it even work with react-native?)
- `remote-redux-devtools` (which we had success with in the past) has been abandoned

Is there any way to use redux devtools with a hermes react-native a on 2022?

Here's our code:

```js
    const enhancer = composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(createDebounce(), thunk, acuityMiddlewareCreator),
        // devTools(remoteDevToolsConfig),
    );
    const store = createStore(persistedReducer, initialState, enhancer);
```

Comment: What did you end up using in the end?

Comment: @RaideR I just posted an answer, check it out.

Comment: Thanks mate. Unfortunately I cannot use Flipper because its not compatible with react-native-firebase and its `use_framworks`. Appreciate your answer though :-).

Comment: @RaideR we are using flipper with react-native-firebase. Here's our podfile in case it helps. https://gist.github.com/SudoPlz/28c844b32031f81c34fd029efa9a1ddf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using [Redux Debugger Plugin for Flipper](https://github.com/jk-gan/flipper-plugin-redux-debugger)

We're not REALLY into flipper, but it looks like it get's the job done for us and it's stable.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[The flipper integration will be deprecated in react native 0.73 and removed in the next release. Furthermore remote debugging will be deprecated in 0.73 and disabled by default as well](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/12/06/0.73-debugging-improvements-stable-symlinks), making redux devtools unusable, however [manually enabling it can help (as long as the option is still available).](https://reactnative.dev/docs/other-debugging-methods#remote-javascript-debugging-deprecated)

For my react native application using Expo 49, Hermes, Redux Toolkit and TypeScript I was able to investigate my redux state using [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron) together with the [Redux plugin](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/blob/master/docs/plugins/redux.md):

1. Install dependencies

```
    npm install --save-dev reactotron-react-native reactotron-redux
```

2. Create config file ReactotronConfig.js in project root

```
    import Reactotron from "reactotron-react-native";
    import { reactotronRedux } from "reactotron-redux";
    
    const reactotron = Reactotron.configure({ name: "React Native App" })
        .useReactNative()
        .use(reactotronRedux())
        .connect();
    
    export default reactotron;
```

3. Add Reactotron to your store

```
    import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import { MyReducer, MyState } from "./MyStore";
    import reactotron from "../../../ReactotronConfig";
    
    export interface AppState {
      myState: MyState;
    }
    
    export const AppStore = configureStore<AppState>({
      reducer: {
        myState: MyReducer,
      },
      enhancers: [reactotron.createEnhancer!()],
    });
```

4. Start your app
5. Start [Reactotron Desktop application](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/releases?q=reactotron-app&expanded=true) and reload your app

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron, it's very similaire to react native debugger, it has redux devtools I hope you will like it :)

Comment: We've used it in the past but it's different from redux devtools, and it's running very slow on our devices. It's super slow to get a snapshot of the state, and to be honest I prefer redux devtools.
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: It's an outdated repo and doesn't support M1 Apple Silicon by default